# How to override disabled hyperlinks styling?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to override the styling that is applied to a hyperlink if it has the `disabled="disabled"` attribute?

It's currently greyed out. Not bothered about making it an active link, just want to change the font, color, etc.

**UPDATE :** Must work in IE6, IE7 & FF

**UPDATE :** 
It's worse than I though the html is `<A id="someId" disabled>About Your Group</A>`

**UPDATE :** 
I'm going to really have to see what is adding this 'disabled' to the links.. I *think* it's a jquery plugin.. (ui.tabs, [jquery ui.tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs))

Comment: use the !important in your css

Comment: Unless you are loading/generating HTML dynamically, it's not jQuery thats putting in the disabled properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `disabled` property can't be used on `a` elements. it only applies to `input`, `select` and `button` elements.

Sure; Internet Explorer puts a bevel-effect on links with this property set. FireFox, on the other hand, ignores this property completely.

***Note:*** Links will still function. Their default behavior is NOT prevented--they just look disabled. They do not behave like a disabled text input.



You are better off using a class to signal if a link is disabled. This will work cross-browser as well...:

The CSS

```
.disabled { color: #ccc; }
```

The HTML

```
<a href="..." class="disabled">...</a>
```

And to complete the disabled effect; using jQuery, you can select all links with the class "disabled" and prevent their default behavior, like so:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("a.disabled").click(function ()
    {
        // return false to disable the link (preventDefault = true)
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Behavior exactly as you described. You just cured my headache.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that ASP.Net puts disabled="disabled" on `<a>` tags when setting the `Enable` property to `false` on an `<asp:HyperLink>`.

This causes css-rules for that element to be ignored in IE (even for `a[disabled="disabled]`!), which is extremely annoying. Other browsers don't care, since they ignore that property.

My solution was to simply set the `NavigationUrl` property to `null` in the code-behind for the elements I wanted to disable.

The advantage of doing this server side instead of with JavaScript is that it will work even if users have JavaScript turned off.

Comment: It does this it for LinkButtons too, and they don't have a NavigateUrl property. So I went for a[disabled=disabled]{color:Gray !important; text-decoration:none !important; } in the css. Probably doesn't meet the full requirements of this question, but good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know to what extent the `disabled` attribute is supported for hyperlinks. Make sure you test thoroughly.
I see two ways of targeting this in CSS:

**CSS 2.1**

You can try the CSS 2.1 attribute selector

```
a[disabled=disabled] { color: blue }
```

I think this is most likely to work with a non-form element. Doesn't work in IE <= 6. [**Quirksmode compatibility table**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html).

**CSS 3**

In CSS 3, it's possible to use the `:disabled` pseudo-class ([**source**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/))

```
input:disabled {  background-color: yellow; }
```

doesn't work in any IE including 8. Works in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. [**Quirksmode compatibility table**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

I've never seen `disabled` used on a normal hyperlink so you will have to try whether that works. Per the specification, the `disabled` pseudo-class is for disabled *form elements* only.

Comment: These didnt work i'm afraid a[disabled] could target it but not override the text color.

Comment: @Lee If it can target it, I'm quite sure you can override it. Is this a normal hyperlink? Can you try !important? (You can then use Firebug to find out where the offending definition is.)

Comment: @Lee can you show the markup you're using for the disabled link? I'm trying to reproduce it but not getting any greying out.

Comment: It could also be that this jquery plugin (ui.tabs) is messing with the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Whe you're using ASP.NET, and you disable a `LinkButton` on server side, the html generated is an `<a>` tag with `disabled="disabled"` non-standard attribute. However, there's no `href` attribute generated, so that the link will not behave like a link in any of the browsers.

The problem is that IE adds the typical "bevel effect" to the disabled link, and the other browsers render it as "regular text".

You can solve the problem in non-IE browsers styling like this:

```
a:not([href]) /* this is for ASP.NET disabled links */
{
  opacity: .5; /* all but IE before 9 */
}
```

The problem is that IE (at least up to IE 8) keeps doing the "bevel" effect on the disabled link. To make IE behave like the other browsers you need to change the CSS style, adding this non-standard filter attirbute (only works for IE):

`filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

And you also need to use some javascript, i.e. jQuery, to remove the offending disabled attribute. I.e.

`$('#controlId').attr('disabled','')`

If your case is even more strange, and you have `disabled` and `href`, you should remove also the `href` so that the style can be applied and the link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a 'disabled' attribute for hyperlink (anyway it doesn't respect w3c recommandations) but you can try to add class for styling these elements like :

```
<a class="inactive" ...>...</a>
```

And for the css :

```
a.inactive {
  color:#000
}
```